# Why can't I see some files in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, microsoft-surface-pro

I installed wsl on my surface pro x. Explorer.exe or cmd.exe shows the wsl.exe but Powershell doesn't.

I don't know why that happens.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try this on a production version of Windows 10. The version above is an Insider Evaluation build, so the first thing is to try in Production

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit powershell.exe?

Comment: @grawity: I tried both of 32-bit and 64-bit and the results are the same.

Comment: @John: The new Surface Pro X is based on ARM and WSL1 doesn't support ARM so I had to use the Insider Program to try WSL2.

Comment: Windows 10 Version 2004 is out today. Have you tried that to see if a newer version works?